# Error message when executing stored procedure that creates table 

Tags: sql-server

```
alter procedure SP_employeedetails
(
 @tablename varchar(50),
 @empname varchar(50),
 @age int,
 @address varchar (50)
)
as
begin
declare @xxx varchar(50)
set  @xxx= 'create table '+@tablename+'
( '+@empname+'varchar(50),
   '+@age+' int ,
    '+@address+' varchar(50)
)'
print @xxx
exec (@xxx)
end
```

When I excecuted this   using the statement

```
exec SP_employeedetails 'Employeedetails', 'jhon', 25, 'cochin'
```

following error message was displayed

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Procedure SP_employeedetails, Line 11
>   
> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'create table
>   Employeedetails   ( jhonvarchar(50),
>        ' to data type int.

Comment: Your passing @age as varchar '25' pass it in as an int 25 and convert to varchar, or declare the parameter as a varchar.

Comment: @age is an INT parameter which cannot be 'added' to a string. Besides, it would be an invalid column name.

Comment: You need a space between the column name and data type.

Comment: where i need to change for the sp to get excecuted ,devio ?

Comment: bleeeah , sorry i have exceuted it like exec SP_employeedetails 'Employeedetails','jhon',25,'cochin'

Comment: Are you really trying to create a new table every time an employee is added? It seems like this code should be performing an insert, not a create table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A few potential problems:

1. space between column name and data type
2. attempt to add an int to a string
3. your string could almost certainly exceed 50 characters
4. the age column name is a number - this needs to be properly escaped. I escaped all to be safe. You should watch out for an `@empname` like `Jimmy O'Shea` or addresses like `253 Main Street` - these column names won't be valid in your current script.
5. 50 characters is clearly not enough for your string. Let's try it:

```sql
declare @xxx varchar(50)

set  @xxx= 'create table employeedetails
( john varchar(50),
   [25] int ,
    cochin varchar(50)
)'

print @xxx;
```

Results:

```
create table employeedetails
( john varchar(50),
```

Here is how I would do it:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.SP_employeedetails
(
 @tablename varchar(50),
 @empname varchar(50),
 @age int,
 @address varchar (50)
)
as
begin
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(2000); -- 50 is unlikely enough

  SET @sql = N'create table dbo.' + @tablename + '
  ( ' + QUOTENAME(@empname) + ' varchar(50), -- need space here
   '+ QUOTENAME(CONVERT(VARCHAR(12), @age) +' int , -- need to convert this and delimit
    '+ QUOTENAME(@address) + ' varchar(50)
  );';

  PRINT @sql;
  EXEC sp_executesql @sql;
END
GO
```

However, as I mentioned in a comment, are you really creating a new *table* for every employee that's added to your system? It seems like this should be inserting a row into a table, not creating a whole new table.

And finally, [you should not be using the `SP_` prefix for stored procedures](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115%28v=vs.100%29.aspx).

Comment: SET @sql = N'create table dbo.'+@tablename+' what is this N stand for ?

Comment: @BABURAJVD http://databases.aspfaq.com/general/why-do-some-sql-strings-have-an-n-prefix.html

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a whitespace before the type:

```
'+@empname+'varchar(50),
```

And you must cast the @age parameter to a `varchar` type.

Comment: I think that's half the answer.

Comment: Correct, as @Marek already provided the other half. I'll update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

<sub>[My answer explains the error you're getting, but it is the least of your problems - [Aaron's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12494937/95) contains a detailed analysis of them]</sub>

You need to explicitly convert `@age` to `varchar`.

[Data Type Precedence](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309.aspx):

> When an operator combines two expressions of different data types, the rules for data type precedence specify that the data type with the lower precedence is converted to the data type with the higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. When both operand expressions have the same data type, the result of the operation has that data type.

Data type `int` has higher precedence than `varchar`, so SQL Server tries to convert `@xxx` to `int`.

Comment: I think that's half the answer.

Comment: Then, what changes to be done in the code ,for creating a table having int column and varchar column through stored procedures?

Comment: @BABURAJVD Read the linked article one more time - your problem and the data type precedence have nothing to do with creating tables. This issue appears when you try to combine **two expressions of different data types** - in your case, it's an attempt to concatenate `varchar` and `int` variables.